# Worklight - error: property 'callbackId' not found on object of type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand *'

Tags: ios, xcode5, ibm-mobilefirst, xcodebuild

I have a **"worklight"** project with iPhone Environment. Using **Ant Task** i have generated the native iPhone folder. I am tying to compile and package the native iPhone project using command line tool `xcodebuild`. It gives me the following error.

```
 error: property 'callbackId' not found on object of type 'CDVInvokedUrlCommand *'
```

But if i open the native iPhone project in `Xcode` and try to build and archive it works fine. I am not sure why my command line xcodebuild for the same fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just FYI: this is being investigated.

Comment: Hi Idan, Thanks. I am using IBM Worklight 6.1 fix pack 1. xCode version is Xcode 5.1, Build version 5B130a, Command line tool is Xcode 5.1 Build version 5B130a. Worklight ANT TASK library version from IBM Worklight Server version 6.1 fix-pack 1. Hope this will help your team to investigate in detail.

Comment: Hi Idan, Here is my Ant Script for iOS compile and package.<echo level="info">QA Compiling...</echo>
  <exec executable="xcodebuild" dir="${IOS_PROJECT_ROOT_QA}"
   failonerror="true">
   <arg line="-project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj"/>
   <arg line="-alltargets" />
   <arg line="-sdk ${TARGET_SDK}" />
            <arg line="-arch armv7"/>
            <arg line="-configuration ${CONFIGURATION_NAME}" />
            <arg line="CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR='${PROJECT_BUILD_LOCATION_DEV}'"/>
  </exec>

Comment: Hi Idan, I have raised a PMR with IBM. Seems like, its a product defect. Even with a simple HelloWorld project while generating the native code base via Ant Task and compile / package the same using Xcoddbuild command line tool gives the error.

Comment: PMR Service request number: 75170 7TD 000

Comment: Thanks. The PMR will take its course now...

Comment: Does it happen also when building the project with the Studio (not using the Ant task)?

Comment: No, Build via xCode IDE success. But using AntTask, xcodebuild command line tool, it fails.

Comment: @PVR, any update since? Could it be that the used ant task was not from the same Worklight version used?

Comment: Hi Idan. Thanks. After applying fix pack 2 for Worklight Server / studio, the build jar works fine. I totally forget to update this tread. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @PVR Please write the above as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by upgrading the Worklight Studio and Server installations to Worklight 6.2.0.02 (Fix Pack 2). After upgrading the Ant task script then properly compiled the native project.